# How to create a Multinline textbox growing dynamically without scrollbars?

Tags: facebook, textbox, resize, textinput

I need to use a text-box (multiline) in my application. It need to grow as the user inputs text into it. I want that textbox to grow without any scrollbars. I tried `allow=resize:null` but it just prevents textbox from being stretched.All i want is a textbox as we see in facebook comment /share area which grows simply without any scrollbars on sides. I hope i have neatly explained it.

Comment: What is the programming language you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this: (Source: [Expandable or Auto-Resize TextBox Height by Colt Kwong](http://weblogs.asp.net/coltk/archive/2010/05/30/expandable-or-auto-resize-textbox-height.aspx))

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMsg" runat="server"  TextMode="MultiLine" 
style="overflow:hidden" onkeyup="AutoExpand(this, event)" Rows="2" />
```

using this javascript:

```
    function AutoExpand(txtBox, event) 
{
    if (event.keyCode == "13" || event.keyCode == "8") {
        var therows = 0
        var thetext = document.getElementById(txtBox.id).value;
        var newtext = thetext.split("\n");
        therows += newtext.length

        document.getElementById(txtBox.id).rows = therows;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or if you like jquery you should take a look at the [jQuery autoResize Plugin](https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery.fn.autoResize).

> A plugin for jQuery which changes the dimensions of input elements to
>   suit the amount of data entered. It operates on textarea,
>   input[type=text] and input[type=password] elements.

Usage is as follows:

```
$('textarea#foo').autoResize();
```

You can pass options:

```
$('textarea#foo').autoResize({
    maxHeight: 200,
    minHeight: 100
});
```

Comment: Thanks for ur time... I tell after testing it

Comment: is there a non jquery method that you know of?

Comment: The answer is good. But how i can i implement it in asp.net . The demo code was good. But when i tried it it did not work

Comment: I've updated my answer with another sollution. Maybe you'll like this more.